# Association in Cakephp 3x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm trying set association in cakephp
[my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xq6b.png)
two model:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
class UsersTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {

        $this->hasOne('Scores',[
            'className' => 'Scores',
            'conditions' => '',
            'dependent' => true
        ]);
    }

}
```

and

```
class ScoresTable extends Table {
    //var $name = 'Scores';
    public final $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongTo('Users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_code_Student',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        );
    }
}
```

function index in controller:

```
public function index() {
    //$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $modelUser = $this->loadModel('Users');
    $dataUser = $modelUser->find('all')->contain(['Score']);
    /*$data = array(
        /*'listUser' => $modelUser->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('email LIKE' => '%gmail.com'),
            'limit' => 2
        )),$connection
                ->execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email like :email limit 3', ['email' => '%gmail.com'])
                ->fetchAll('assoc')
        'listUser' => $this->paginate($modelUser->find('all')),
        'title' => 'Demo MVC'
    );*/
    $data = array(
        'listUser' => $dataUser
    );
    $this->set('data', $data);

}
```

When I run it, the following error is shown: `Users is not associated with Score`

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your relation looks like invalid.Try this:

**users table**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{

    $this->hasOne('Scores',[
        'foreignKey' => 'user_code_Student'
    ]);
}
```

**scores table**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->belongsTo('Users', // you wrote here belongTo that should be belongsTo instead
        'foreignKey' => 'user_code_Student', // is user_code_Student foreignKey ???
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    );
}
```

And also change this:

```
$dataUser = $modelUser->find('all')->contain(['Scores']); // not Score
```

Comment: Tks for help. But it still error.
exactly error show : Table "Cake\ORM\Table" is not associated with "Scores"
I new be, and I don't sure convention: name file, name class.
file model: User.php, Score.php
name class model and controller like above.
can you help me ?

Comment: These are basic things on cakephp..And this blog tutorial (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) is perfect place to get started with.Don't avoid basic things.

Comment: And i am sorry I just saw your 'my db' link later...so your foreign key is user_code_Student and i have edited that in answer.

Comment: I learned blog tutorial... and understood this error. tks you so much for help. :)